# Windows somehow got convinced that a file is a folder. How do I change it back?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I recently moved an external drive from my usb-enabled router to my desktop machine, and ran into some permissions-related issues.  A number of files were giving me errors when I tried to take ownership or set permissions, and in all my fiddling on a particular file, it somehow got switched to a folder.

Anyone have any idea how this might have happened, and how to flip it back?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you run a `chkdsk /f` on the drive?  It may be corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between a file and a folder is usually a single flag in the directory entry containing said file/folder.   That said, it seems that maybe this parent directory has incurred some damage, flipping that flag.  Since the contents of the (now) folder do not resemble a valid directory structure, it sees it as empty.  Chkdsk MIGHT find some errors to be fixed, but unlikely.

If obtaining the contents of the data sectors is important, you need a utility which will allow you to read inodes or just raw sectors.   If it's not that important, I'd delete the file and run a GOOD filesystem checker (chkdsk does NOT qualify).